# Showing an error This MinMaxScaler instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method

Tags: python, minmax, inverse-transform

I am trying to get back the original values after predicting Cost.

I used MinMax feature scaling to scale the target feature. I got a scaled output. I am trying to convert them into original values but it shows me an error.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
food[["COST"]] = scaler.fit_transform(food[["COST"]])

scaler.inverse_transform(y)
pd.DataFrame(y,columns=["COST"])
y.to_excel("yg.xlsx",index=False)
```

I am trying to convert the predicted cost value to the original values and save a excel sheet with the original cost values. Please help!

Comment: You missed the parentheses in the second `scaler = MinMaxScaler()`.
And why is the import twice in your code?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Klaus. The second import is on another block of code. It still shows an error though. This time the error is "This MinMaxScaler instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method."

Comment: Could you maybe share more of your code? Without a working example, it's a wild guess only, but you could get an error like that if you replaced your `scaler` with a new instance of `MinMaxScaler()`. Are you sure that you have just one line saying `scaler = MinMaxScaler()`? And is the call to `scaler.fit_transform()` and `scaler.inverse_transform()` within the same scope?

Comment: Hey sg.sysel, I would like to share my code with you but I don't know how to. I'm new here on stack overflow.

Answer (score 7):

Here is what you should do:
Assume ***X*** is your original data, ***X_scaled*** is your scaled data, and you would like to get ***X_hat***, which should be identical to ***X***.

In other words:

```
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

To get ***X_hat***, first you have to create an external MinMaxScaler object:

```
obj = scaler.fit(X)
```

Then you use:

```
X_hat = obj.inverse_transform(X_scaled)
```